# MVC routeValues as object, and html attributes as dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have really annoying problem.
Is it possible to pass routeValues as object and html attributes as dictionary?

I know i can pass both as object, or both as dictionary.

Problem starts here:
I have made an extension method to add attribute to route values dictionary or annoymous objects:

```
public static RouteValueDictionary SetAttributeValue(this object attributes, string attributeName, object attributeValue)
{
    RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes;

    if (attributes == null)
    {
        htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();
    }
    else if (attributes.GetType() == typeof(RouteValueDictionary))
    {
        htmlAttributes = (RouteValueDictionary)attributes;
    }
    else
    {
        htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(attributes);
    }

    htmlAttributes[attributeName] = attributeValue;

    return htmlAttributes;
}
```

I'am using it to add some htmlattributes. Like in this example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString NewWindowActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes.SetAttributeValue("target", "_blank"));
}
```

The problem is it executes this method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
```

And this method don't even check if object is type of dictionary.

So i cannot make my extension to add attributes when using actionlink with objects instead of dictionaries.

I then thought of return ExpandoObject:

```
public static object SetAttributeValue(this object attributes, string attributeName, object attributeValue)
{
    RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes;

    if (attributes == null)
    {
        htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();
    }
    else if (attributes.GetType() == typeof(RouteValueDictionary))
    {
        htmlAttributes = (RouteValueDictionary)attributes;
    }
    else
    {
        htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(attributes);
    }

    htmlAttributes[attributeName] = attributeValue;

    return htmlAttributes.ToAnonymousObject();
}

public static object ToAnonymousObject(this IDictionary<string, object> @this)
{
    var expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
    var expandoDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)expandoObject;

    foreach (var keyValuePair in @this)
    {
        expandoDictionary.Add(keyValuePair);
    }
    return expandoObject;
}
```

Of course it doesn't working, becouse of implementation of `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes;`

So is there any possibility to make it working?
I know i can always define routeValues as RouteValueDictionary, but the reason i'am asking this question is to avoid it

Comment: Can't you define an overload `NewWindowActionLink` with `public static MvcHtmlString NewWindowActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string,object> htmlAttributes)`?

Comment: I know i can... I want to use SetAttributeValue in many places, without thinking of setting routeValues as dictionary. Moreover using annomyous objects looks nicer in code, and is shorter

Comment: "And this method don't even check if object is type of dictionary." Why do you need it to? Isnt that what your method should doing? `var ho = htmlAttributes as IDictionary<string, object>; if (ho!=null) ....`